# Removing malicious training examples from trained linear regression model

Tags: regression, train

Let's say that I trained a linear regression model with $N$ training examples $X$ and targets $y$. After training, I realize that some small subset of training examples $X_e$ were measured erroneously, $|X_e| << N$.

What is the best way to retrain the model, without going through the typical fitting procedure. In my scenario this is not possible because after the model has been trained and the problems detected, I have access to $X$, but not to $y$. I am also aware which elements of  $X$ are in $X_e$.

Comment: What do you actually know about the model?  Just the coefficient estimates?  In general, I would be very cautious about interpreting the model at all given that you don't have access to Y.  (This caution would apply even if you did not have to re-train the model).  Without access to Y, you can't assess the model for lack-of-fit or violation of assumptions, you can't calculate correlation coefficients, you can't understand the potential influence of influential points, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.    Let's say there is one malicious training example, to the right of all other points (with a large $x$-value).  Since you don't know it's $y$-value, you have to consider both of the following possibilities:

- The $y$-value of that malicious point was some huge positive value, which artificially increased the inferred slope -- so that adjustment you need to make is to reduce the slope.
- The $y$-value of that malicious point was some huge *negative* value, which artificially *decreased* the inferred slope -- so that adjustment you need to make is to *increase* the slope.

You have no way to distinguish those two cases, so you can't tell what adjustment to make.